# Proof of Set Theory Algebra using Logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A, B and C be sets.  I am trying to prove that
$$A\cup(B \setminus C)=(A\cup B)\setminus(C\setminus A)$$

And I am supposed to use logic to work through this problem, so first I let

A={x|P}, B={x|Q}, and C={x|R}

Then I did

$$x \in (A\cup(B \setminus C)) \iff x \in \{y| P \lor (Q \land  \neg R\} $$

I have done algebra on it to come to a lot of different things but none of them seem to be getting me in the right direction.  I will list a few of the different places I have gotten if somebody wants to go from there, but besides distributing the P, I don't know what to do.

1. $x \in \{y |(P\lor Q) \land (P\lor \neg R\}$
2. $x \in \{y| ((P\land P)\lor (P \land \neg R)) \lor ((Q \land P) \lor (Q \land \neg R))$
3. $x \in \{y|((P \lor P) \land (P \lor Q)) \lor ((P \lor Q) \land \neg R)\}$

Obviously, my goal would be to get to $x \in \{ y|(P \lor  Q) \land \neg(R \land \neg P)\}$, I could finish from there, but not from where I am.  Thank you to anyone who helps!

Comment: Asaf Karagila, is there any way you can help me with this? I am totally lost!

Comment: If you want to have your comments notified to a concrete person you must use, in this case, @AsafKaragila

Comment: Hint: ~(R ^ ~P) iff (~R v ~~P) iff (~R v P) where ~ is the negation operator. Relate this to your 1st equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to show that

$$x \in \{ y|(P \lor  Q) \land \neg(R \land \neg P)\}=\{ y|(P \lor  Q) \land (P \lor \neg R)\},$$ where we have used $\neg(R \land \neg P)=P \lor \neg R.$

But note that you have shown

$$x \in \{y| P \lor (Q \land  \neg R\}=\{y| (P \lor Q) \land (P \lor \neg R)\},$$

and so you are done.

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
\newcommand{\empty}{\varnothing}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathbin \triangle}
$Here is how I would approach a problem like this: start at the most complex side of the equality, and calculate the elements of that set by expanding the definitions, and using the laws of logic to simplify.

---

In this case, we start with the right hand side of the statement, and calculate for all $\;x\;$ as follows:

$$\calc
x \in (A \cup B) \setminus (C \setminus A)
\calcop\equiv{definition of $\;\setminus\;$}
x \in A \cup B \;\land\; \lnot (x \in C \setminus A)
\calcop\equiv{definitions of $\;\cup\;$ and $\;\setminus\;$}
(x \in A \lor x \in B) \;\land\; \lnot (x \in C \land x \not\in A)
\calcop\equiv{logic: DeMorgan}
(x \in A \lor x \in B) \;\land\; (x \not\in C \lor x \in A)
\calcop\equiv{logic: factor out $\;x \in A\;$, using the fact that $\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\land\;$}
x \in A \;\lor\; (x \in B \land x \not\in C)
\calcop\equiv{definitions of $\;\setminus\;$ and $\;\cup\;$}
x \in A \cup (B \setminus C)
\endcalc$$

By set extensionality, this proves the statement.

---

Note how we make things easy for ourselves by starting with the most complex side, since it is simpler to simplify then to introduce complexity: you have less choice when trying to simplify, so you have less options to consider. That often makes it more straightforward to complete your proof.